# Content broken bootstrap v3.3.7 with laravel v5.4

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.4

When refresh the page then my content broken, I couldn't understand why this happening. Some time's my whole page broken. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Bootstrap v: 3.3.7

laravel v: 5.4**

Here is my code:

```
 @extends('layouts.admin-user.main')

@section('main_content')
    <div class="ptb-80">
        <div class="users-mang">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @include('layouts.success')
                        @include('layouts.errors')
                           <h1>User Management</h1>
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption font-dark">
                                    @if(isset($searchData))
                                        <a href="@if (isset($companyData->company_name)){{ url($companyData->company_name.'/user-list') }}@endif"
                                           class="btn btn-info">Back to User List</a>
                                    @else
                                        <a href="@if (isset($companyData->company_name)){{ url($companyData->company_name.'/user') }}@endif"
                                           class="btn btn-success">Add User</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Import User</a>
                                    @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="tools"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Group</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @if(isset($allData) && !$allData->isEmpty())
                                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                                @foreach($allData as $data)
                                    <?php $i++; ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->phone }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->group_id }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="@if (isset($companyData->company_name)){{ url($companyData->company_name.'/user/contact/'.$data->id) }}@endif"
                                               class="btn btn-info">Contact</a>
                                            <a href="@if (isset($companyData->company_name)){{ url($companyData->company_name.'/user/edit/'.$data->id) }}@endif"
                                               class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                            <a href="@if (isset($companyData->company_name)){{ url($companyData->company_name.'/user/delete/'.$data->id) }}@endif"
                                               onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
                                               class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="6" class="text-center"> No available data.</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Here is a broken content screenshot:

[image: http://prntscr.com/gnrt8d]

Thanks so much.

Comment: you may be missing something. check console log

Comment: Hi Kharoti, There is no console error. I'm didn't find any errors there...